# Proxying data through getters to computed properties (v-model)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

There is the following code when working with `v-model` and `html` with `<input type ="text">` tags:

```
<template>
  <InputTextApp class="inputTextAdditionData" placeholder_text="" v-model="cell_phone_number">
  </InputTextApp>
</template>


<script>
  import InputTextApp from '~/components/FormElements/InputTextApp';

  export default{

  data () {
    return {
      loading_cell_phone_number: '',
    }
  },

  computed: {
    cell_phone_number: {
      get () {
        return this.loading_cell_phone_number;
      },
      set (value) {
        this.loading_cell_phone_number = value;
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

Question:
If in the content of calculated properties it is necessary to have the above code, how should I proxy the data from getters the what would it is code working fine?

As a primitive test, I tried to do something like this:

```
// vuex storage: tracker.js
const axios = require("axios");

export const getters = {
  
  personTypeInput3: (state) => {
      
    return {index: {
      get () {
        return this.loading_cell_phone_number;
      },
      set (value) {
        this.loading_cell_phone_number = value;
      }
    },
  }}
  
};


<template>
  <InputTextApp class="inputTextAdditionData" placeholder_text="" v-model="cell_phone_number">
  </InputTextApp>
</template>


<script>
  import InputTextApp from '~/components/FormElements/InputTextApp';

  export default{

  data () {
    return {
      loading_cell_phone_number: '',
    }
  },

  computed: {
    cell_phone_number: {
    ...mapGetters("tracker", [
    "personTypeInput3",
  ])
}
</script>
```

Then I accepted the content code in a computed property of the following form:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

What needs to be written in the storage getter in order to get the code specified in the very first implementation (at the beginning of the post) in the computed property at the output?
(something like this:)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: A Vuex getter should not mutate state, that's what mutations are for.

Comment: I don't need to mutate anything at all.
The question is not about that.
I just need proxying data to a computed property.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you to use computed as a setter. In this case you lost caching advantage anyway and your code gets more complex. Use methods for that.